# Greyed TWebBrowser control

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

When `TWebBrowser` control is too small it becomes greyed.

If `TWebBrowser` control is aligned to `alClient` and there are no other controls on the form I can make it really small (50x10 for example). However, when I add other controls like panels, toolbar, main menu and so on which all float on top (`alTop`) - the more controls I add it seems, the smaller window of `TWebBrowser` I can get without greying itself. When window is resized to become larger, then it becomes ungreyed again.

In this example I placed `TToolBar` with 2 buttons aligned to `alTop`, and `TWebBrowser` aligned to `alClient`. If I make toolbar invisible, I can make web browser really small. However, with toolbar visible it greys itself. The more controls I add it seems to have less and less usable space before greying itself.

[image: WebBrowser greyed]

As you can see in last example web browser is even smaller than in second example but still visible and everything is the same except there is no toolbar on top. Same applies if used on Windows 7 or 8 or with Internet Explorer 10 or 11.

The examples here are just examples. I don't have a problem with having 100x100 control as minimum size. The problem is that when I place quite a bit of controls then it doesn't allow me to have smaller control than 550x250, which is quite large.

Can anyone enlighten me why other controls have an effect on web browser not being able to use smaller size when it can do this perfectly normally when there are no other controls on form?

Comment: I believe it's the scroll bars of the `TWebBrowser` you see that are grayed. if you'll drop the `TWebBrowser` on a panel with alClient (for both controls), you could set `Constraints` for the panel with `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to 100 for example. so that the `TWebBrowser` could not be re-sized to 10x10.

Comment: I would be perfectly happy with 100x100 (no point in using 10x10) but the problem is the whole webbrowser becomes greyed if I have toolbar and other controls if size is smaller than 300x200 which is quite large. No, **whole** control is greyed, scrollbars disappear completely. Same thing happens during design mode too if form is resized to be too small.

Comment: Post some pictures to illustrate what you mean (before and after resize). I can't reproduce.

Comment: Added picture to the question.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with D2009, XE but but with XE3. I can't say why it occurs, but as workaround you could place the webbrowser on e.g. panel (both align alClient).

Comment: Coder, when you refer to someone with comment, use e.g. @bummi :)

Comment: @bummi Can you make this into an answer so that others can know about this workaround?

Comment: @Coder12345 feel free to answer and accept your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks to bummi in the comments up there for finding a following workaround:

It appears that the problem with greyed control doesn't appear in XE3 and later but can be reproduced in earlier versions like XE2, XE, 2010 and 2009.

For these earlier versions the workaround is to place `TWebBrowser` on another control such as `TPanel` and then align both controls to `alClient` (so that the `TWebBrowser` fills entire `TPanel` and `TPanel` fills entire area previously filled by `TWebBrowser`). Of course, alignment here is not an issue but the workaround is just to place one control on another.

The same works for `TEmbeddedWB` and probably other controls that host Internet Explorer ActiveX control.

When placed on container control like `TPanel`, web browser can be resized to any size without the problem described above.